# Can we use Sirikit for voice recognition

Tags: ios, objective-c, sirikit, speech-recognition-api

I have implemented voice recognition in my application for voice to text conversion using [Nuance Dragon SDK](https://developer.nuance.com/public/index.php?task=prodDev). I have also tried [Open Ears](http://www.politepix.com/openears/) but couldn't get it to work properly. Once conversion is completed I use that text as command to trigger action in my application.

I am wondering if using [Sirikit](https://developer.apple.com/sirikit/) we can do it within application. I was not able to understand it while checking the [WWDC16 Sirikit Introduction](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/217/). May be my interpretation of the intent is not clear but as for as I understood, there's no custom intent to trigger some action inside the application.

Plus is sirikit available for objective C as well or just Swift?

Comment: This are two Q. Please take the last one out and make it a separate Q. However, the Sirikit classes inherits from `NSObject` and you have a Objective-C reference for it. (Just follow your link.) Likely the biggest parts of Sirikit are developed in C and Objective-C. Apple would be crazy to write an important framework in a programming language that even is not stable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SiriKit is for integrating with Siri outside of the context of your application. However, Apple did releases a Speech Recognition API for iOS 10 as well that sounds more like what you want. You can learn more about it here: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/509/

All Apple Frameworks are usable by Objective-C and Swift.